# How to use some param to get React component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to according to different param render different views  in a Component , these views from some template.
`Main.js`

```
render() {
  const{ data, isEdit } = this.props
  console.log('Detail data:', data)
  console.log('isEdit:', isEdit)
  return <div>
  {getView(data)}
 </div>
}
```

`getView`

```
function getView(data) {
  let modelName = getModelName(data.PolciyName)
  modelName = 'M1'
  if (modelName) {
    let Model = require(`./models/${modelName}`)
    console.log('getView- modelName', modelName)
    console.log('typeof', typeof M1) //Object
    return <div><Model data={data} /></div>
    } else {
    return <div>no data</div>
  }
}
```

`M1`

```
function M1(data) {
  return <div>
    <h2>{data.name}</h2>
  </div>
}
```

and this code can't work, It will get a error.
`Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of`Main`.`

Answer (score 0):

When calling {getView(data)} in render,

try using {this.getView(data)} instead, same with any reference to the function M1. If memory serves me right it's because JavaScript works a little differently to other OO languages in that it doesn't actually have classes, so you have to explicitly state the scope even locally within the component.

Comment: `getView` is a import function,`import { getView } from './viewUtils'`, so `this.getView` is `undefined`